# Cant swap USDC for USDT with UniswapV2Router02

Tags: ethereum, solidity, swap, smartcontracts

I am trying to swap some `USDC(0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48)` token for `USDT(0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7)` token using `UniswapV2Router02` at address `0xd9e1cE17f2641f24aE83637ab66a2cca9C378B9F`(this is the Sushiswap's router on Ethereum mainnet)

Since I both `USDC` and `USDT` have 6 digits precision as `amountIn` to the `swapExactTokensForTokens` method I am passing number `3000 * 10 ** 6`(must be equal to $3000). As `amountOutMin` I am passing `2850 * 10 ** 6`(must be equal to $2850, which is -5% from the `amountIn`. In my opinion this is prety enough slippage tolerance)

Everything looks right? Yes but no! Everythime I ma trying to run this code:

```
UniswapV2Router(0xd9e1cE17f2641f24aE83637ab66a2cca9C378B9F) // Sushiswap router on ETH mainnet
.swapExactTokensForTokens(3000 * 10 ** 6, // 3000 USDC
                          2850 * 10 ** 6, // 2850 USDT
                          [
                            "0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48", // USDC address on ETH mainnet
                            "0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7" // USDT address on ETH mainnet
                          ],
                            msg.sender,
                            <some deadline>);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Revert message: UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT
```

Please help what I am missing?

**EDIT:** I am using `truffle` and I have forked ETH mainnet

**EDIT 2:** The amount `UniswapV2Router` is trying to return is `1327704386 ~ 1327 USDT` which is `~60%` slippage but in the liquidity pair there are assets for `$2,036,392,078,752.44`

Answer (score 0):

It happened so thath the [Sushiswap's USDC/USDT pool](https://analytics.sushi.com/pairs/0xd86a120a06255df8d4e2248ab04d4267e23adfaa) has only `5k` in liquidity and everything with my code is right.